# Python - TypeError: o objeto 'int' não é iterável

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Esse aqui é o meu código:

```
import csv

def gravar(nome,idade, sexo):
    with open('cadastros.csv', 'w') as arquivo_csv:
        colunas = ['Nome', 'Idade', "Sexo"]
        escrever = csv.DictWriter(arquivo_csv, fieldnames=colunas, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        escrever.writeheader()
        escrever.writerow({'Nome' : nome, 'Idade' : idade, "Sexo" : sexo})

def ler():
   with open('cadastros.csv','r') as f:
       leitor = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
       for row in leitor:
           idades = row['Idade']
           idade = int(idades)
           soma = sum(idade)
           print(soma)


while True:

    print("1-Cadastrar Cliente\n"+
          "2-Idade Média\n"+
          "3-Sair\n")

    opcao = int(input("Coloque a opção desejada: \n"))

    if opcao == 1:
        quant = int(input("Quantidade de Clientes que você vai cadastrar!!"))
        for cliente in range(quant):
            nome = input("Coloque o nome do cliente: \n")
            idade = int(input("Coloque a idade do cliente: \n"))
            sexo = input("Coloque o sexo do cliente: \n")
            gravar(nome,idade,sexo)

    elif opcao == 2:
        ler()

    elif opcao == 3:
        print("\nSaindo!!")
        break
```

Eu estou tentando fazer um cadastro de clientes via csv, e também tenho que calcular a média de todas as idade de todos os clientes. Estou pegando as idades de cada um, transformando para inteiro nesse código:

```
def ler():
   with open('cadastros.csv','r') as f:
       leitor = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
       for row in leitor:
           idades = row['Idade']
           idade = int(idades)
           soma = sum(idade)
           print(soma)
```

Porém ele sempre da esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/deagu.LAPTOP-13J3Q2U9/Desktop/Teste2/cadastros.py", line 37, in <module>
    ler()
  File "C:/Users/deagu.LAPTOP-13J3Q2U9/Desktop/Teste2/cadastros.py", line 16, in ler
    soma = sum(idade)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `sum` trabalhar com objetos iteráveis, e você está passando um `int` para a mesma:

```
idade = int(idades)
soma = sum(idade)
```

---

Você pode corrigir esse trecho, criando um acumulador simples das idades, veja um exemplo:

```
def ler():
   with open('cadastros.csv','r') as f:
       leitor = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
       idades = 0
       for row in leitor:
           idades = idades + int(row['Idade'])

       print(idades)
```

Caso você queira realmente utilizar a função `sum`, você precisa fazer alguns ajustes, filtrando a *Idade* dentro da mesma e convertendo para `int`:

```
def ler():
   with open('cadastros.csv','r') as f:
       leitor = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
       idades = 0
       idades = sum([int(row['Idade']) for row in leitor])
       print(idades)
```

---

Qualquer um dos exemplos acima, vai corrigir o seu erro, mas se você perceber, só está sendo cadastrado um cliente no seu csv, isso porque quando o arquivo já existe, você está sobrescrevendo os dados:

```
with open('cadastros.csv', 'w') as arquivo_csv:
```

Para corrigir isso, você precisa abrir o arquivo de forma que ele mantendo os dados anteriores, appendando os novos:

```
with open('cadastros.csv', 'a+') as arquivo_csv:
```

Também será necessário tratar o cabeçalho do csv, pois ele precisa ser escrito somente uma vez, para isso você pode verificar a existência do arquivo, utilizando por exemplo o `Path` da `pathlib`, veja um exemplo de como a função `gravar` ficaria:

```
from pathlib import Path

def gravar(nome,idade, sexo):
    header = not Path('cadastros.csv').is_file()

    with open('cadastros.csv', 'a+') as arquivo_csv:
        colunas = ['Nome', 'Idade', "Sexo"]
        escrever = csv.DictWriter(arquivo_csv, fieldnames=colunas, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        if header:
          escrever.writeheader()
        escrever.writerow({'Nome' : nome, 'Idade' : idade, "Sexo" : sexo})
```

Por fim, a sua função ler, não verifica se o arquivo existe antes de fazer uso do mesmo, com isso é gerada uma exceção, aqui também podemos fazer a verificação de existência do arquivo usando o `pathlib`:

```
def ler():
    if Path('cadastros.csv').is_file():
        with open('cadastros.csv','r') as f:
            leitor = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
            idades = sum([int(row['Idade']) for row in leitor])
            print(f"Média das idades {idades}\n")
    else:
        print("Não existem clientes cadastrados\n")
```

---

Seu código completo então ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

def gravar(nome,idade, sexo):
    header = not Path('cadastros.csv').is_file()

    with open('cadastros.csv', 'a+') as arquivo_csv:
        colunas = ['Nome', 'Idade', "Sexo"]
        escrever = csv.DictWriter(arquivo_csv, fieldnames=colunas, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        if header:
            escrever.writeheader()
        escrever.writerow({'Nome' : nome, 'Idade' : idade, "Sexo" : sexo})

def ler():
    if Path('cadastros.csv').is_file():
        with open('cadastros.csv','r') as f:
            leitor = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
            idades = sum([int(row['Idade']) for row in leitor])
            print(f"Média das idades {idades}\n")
    else:
        print("Não existem clientes cadastrados\n")

while True:

    print("1-Cadastrar Cliente\n"+
          "2-Idade Média\n"+
          "3-Sair\n")

    opcao = int(input("Coloque a opção desejada: \n"))

    if opcao == 1:
        quant = int(input("Quantidade de Clientes que você vai cadastrar: "))
        for cliente in range(quant):
            nome = input("Coloque o nome do cliente: \n")
            idade = int(input("Coloque a idade do cliente: \n"))
            sexo = input("Coloque o sexo do cliente: \n")
            gravar(nome,idade,sexo)

    elif opcao == 2:
        ler()

    elif opcao == 3:
        print("\nSaindo!!")
        break
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/LeafyTenseBits

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: Muito Obrigado Daniel Mendes, vc resolveu o meu problema e me ajudou bastante!!